# SYNTAX error in vba upload in access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update few fields in an Access Database from an Excel file through vba. The field formats are identical. However, I am facing an error message with following text:

**run time error (syntax error in FROM clause)**

following is my code:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws1, Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim mySQLst As String
Dim IDd As Long
Dim dbPath
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Ws1 = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")


dbPath = Ws1.Range("V1").Value
Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
CN.Open "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & dbPath

Set Rst = New ADODB.Recordset

For i = 2 To Ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    IDd = Ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    mySQLst = "SELECT * FROM Test_Table1 WHERE (((Test_Table1.ID1)=16));"

    Rst.Open mySQLst, CN, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdTable

        While Not Rst.EOF
            Rst!TASK_STATUS = Ws1.Cells(i, 13).Value
            Rst!TASK_COMPLETED_DATE = Ws1.Cells(i, 14).Value
            Rst!RESPONSE = Ws1.Cells(i, 15).Value
        Rst.MoveNext
        Wend
Next i

Rst.Close
Set Rst = Nothing
CN.Close
Set CN = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have my activeX library 2.5 active from reference.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with SQL. However, loop code does not make sense. It is editing the same set of records in each iteration of range.

Comment: Yes, I was testing the code which I was to apply for a larger dataset. I have a dynamic range for the ID1 (I'd put 16 for a test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues with your code:
Once you fix that error you will see a bunch more.

1. To fix the error you have asked about please try using Named fields in your recordset:
   eg:

   "SELECT TASK_STATUS, TASK_COMPLETED_DATE, RESPONSE FROM  Test_Table1 WHERE Test_Table1.ID1=16;"
2. If you have a column in your spreadsheet containing ID1 value, you need to replace the "16" in the select statement with that cell each time you loop through.
3. remove the rst.movenext -  you only want to update one record.
4. change the While Not Rst.EOF to IF Not Rst.EOF (update if there is a record, not loop)

Things will work much better for you after these changes.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your detailed suggestion. I will apply the changes. However, what gave me immediate solution for the error that I was receiving (Syntax error in From clause) when I removed the following code:
`Options:=adcmdtable` while opening the recordset.
Thanks Again!